# Link HTML files that are in a folder?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, include, directory

Repeating parts of my webpages are put in a seperate HTML file and included on every page that uses those parts (a header for example). That way I would only have to change it once and every page header is updated automatically. This works fine on pages that are in the site root. However, when I include the header on pages in a folder I would have to change all "example.html" links to "../example.html" links so it will link to the parent folder. When I do this, the header links on pages in the site root are broken because it will search for the files in the parent folder of the site root. I would like to have just **one header file** and use it on every page, whether it is in the site root or in a folder.

My solution was to create two different header files. One of them has "example.html" links to use on pages in the site root, and the other has "../example.html" links to use on pages in a folder. This is the only solution I have so far, and I think it's very inefficient to use two different files when the only difference is the "../" before every link.

Question: is this really the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you begin your URLs with a leading slash, they'll be relative to the base URL instead of relative to your current page's URL. For example:

```
Current Page: http://example.com/about.html
Link:         <a href="/index.html">
Result Page:  http://example.com/index.html

Current Page: http://example.com/directory/about.html
Link:         <a href="/index.html">
Result Page:  http://example.com/index.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Like explained in the comment above I changed all the "example.html" and "../example.html" links to "/example.html" links. Unfortunately now every link is broken. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where are they pointing? What broken link shows up in your address bar?

Comment: Assuming I want to be able to navigate to **http://example.com/about.html** I want the link to work on both the **http://example.com/index.html** and the **http://example.com/folder/page.html** page. I'm also trying to make the links from **http://example.com/folder/page.html** to **http://example.com/folder/page2.html** work. Perhaps I should add a leading slash at the end of the link too? I'm getting 404 not found errors on pages and images won't show up.

Comment: @EloyMillenniaGotjé Can you copy/paste the URL in your address bar here so we can debug the problem?

Comment: My bad!!! The links do work online (not offline)! Very strange by the way, but it works now. Thanks alot :)

Comment: @EloyMillenniaGotjé Ah, were you running the links out of your local filesystem? Leading slashes will only work if you're running a local server or on a real domain - otherwise they'll point to the root directory of your hard drive.